# Why does goog.crypt.base64.decodeStringToByteArray(string) return a invalid byte array here?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-closure-library

I have following problem when working with googles Closure-Library.

```
var temp = "ks/ZUl6L5v77y7BHymYrFw====";  //sample string
var decoded = goog.crypt.base64.decodeStringToByteArray(temp);
var sha512 = new goog.crypt.Sha512();
sha512.update(decoded);
//Error: message must be a byte array
```

Changing the string makes the code run:

```
var temp1 = "heyeveryone";  //sample string
var decoded1 = goog.crypt.base64.decodeStringToByteArray(temp1);
var sha512 = new goog.crypt.Sha512();
sha512.update(decoded1);
//fine...
```

When having a look at the 'decoded'and 'decoded1' values, both look like byte arrays to me.

decoded
  [146, 207, 217, 82, 94, 139, 230, 254, 251, 203, 176, 71, 202, 102, 43, 23, 260]

decoded1
  [133, 236, 158, 189, 234, 242, 162, 119]

So, what's the problem here? Why is 'decoded1' valid and 'decoded' not?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably because `"ks/ZUl6L5v77y7BHymYrFw===="` is not a valid base64-encoded string? Where did you get it from?

Comment: You are right, thank you for your comment! I got the string from a a serverside application and have to do some work on client side.
With this bug fixed, the programs works fine. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first array is *not* a byte array -- `260` (the final value) is not a byte value. Ensure that your encoded values are not more than `255`.

Comment: You are right, that was the problem! Reason for that was, that I got a wrong string, as @Bergi mentioned. Thanks

Comment: I would consider above a bug in `decodeStringToByteArray`, it should not just decode the spurious `==` characters to any invalid value.